# Хранение и удаление значений из массива

Tags: php, массивы, сессия

Есть массив  ID товаров. Пользователь может выбрать 1 товар много раз. То есть, в массиве будет много одинаковых ID одного и того же товара.
Сама суть: как правильно хранить ID о товарах, чтобы потом не было проблем с удалением? Ведь, например, если будет 5 единиц товара с ID 2, то массив будет такой:

```
[2,2,2,2,2]
```

Как потом удалить ID на нужной позиции?
Пробовал простым перебором и проверкой на совпадение, но выходит, что удалить хочу ID со 2-й позиции, а удаляется с 0-й так как условие совпало.
И в итоге удаление работает не так, как нужно.

Comment: Записывайте время добавления в массив :)

Comment: Ну если айдишки у них одинаковые, то предположу что товары одинаковые, и без разницы какой вы товар удаляете. Если товары уникальны, но имеют один ID, то нужен идентификатор уникальный для них

Comment: Как бы да, но если я удалю первый совпавший, то, например, 5-й по счёту ID сдвинется, но при этом индекс останется 5. Я проверял. Значение на первом месте в массиве, но индекс 18. И получается, что в цикле i не доходит до 18 так как в массиве на самом деле всего 5 значений. Но у них индексы 22, 16, 56. Я не знаю как так